# Indenting text in \tabfill (tabbing environment)

Tags: tabbing

I am not an expert in LaTeX. Thus, the question may sound trivial. I am using the tabbing environment, and I have long lines to wrap. Thus, I am using the `\tabfill` command in order to do so.

```
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%\dimen@\linewidth%
\advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin%
\advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab%
\parbox[t]\dimen@{#1\ifhmode\strut\fi}%
% or, to avoid stretching:
% \parbox[t]\dimen@{\raggedright #1\ifhmode\strut\fi}%
}
```

The only problem that I have with this command is that the text inside the `\tabfill` box is aligned to the left margin. I would like that when this text is wrapped (since it is inside a tabbing environment) it is also indented in the rows following the first. Any idea about how to modify this tabfill command in order to achieve this goal? Or any other solution?

Example of what I am looking for:

```
Column 1                Column 2
bla bla                 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        bla bla bla bla
bla bla                 bla bla
```

Code (generating no indent):

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3.1cm} \= \kill
Column 1 \> Column 2\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla}
\end{tabbing}
```

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get from your original code (the first setting to `\dimen@` uncommented):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \dimen@\linewidth
  \advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin
  \advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab
  \parbox[t]\dimen@{#1\ifhmode\strut\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\textwidth=.75\textwidth % just to make wrapping more evident

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3.1cm} \= \kill
Column 1 \> Column 2\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's add a `\leftskip` setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \dimen@\linewidth
  \advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin
  \advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab
  \parbox[t]\dimen@{%
    \leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}#1\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\strut\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\textwidth=.75\textwidth % just to make wrapping more evident

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3.1cm} \= \kill
Column 1 \> Column 2\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't plan using very complicated things inside the argument to `\tabfill` such as itemized or enumerated lists, this is the simplest solution. If you want to add `\raggedright`, place it in front of `\leftskip`.

Comment: If the argument to ``\tabfill`` contains real words with some length, as e.g. ``Include longs words like extracurricular`` rather than ``bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla``, you'll notice a very poor result with respect to justification and hyphenation, in that the distance between each word is much too large, and no hyphenation occurs. Any way to fix that problem?

Comment: @Sverre Try `\RaggedRight` (before the setting of `\leftskip`); you need `\usepackage{ragged2e}` for that command.

Comment: It fixes the interword space issue, but it doesn't lead to hyphenation where it should. As in my example sentence, you'd expect ``extra-curricular``, but instead you get a lot of white space at the end of the first line, almost equal to the length of the word ``extracurricular``. That is, instead of hyphenating the word, it just pushes the entire word to the next line.

Comment: Is there something in your definition of ``tabfill`` that prevents hyphenation?

Comment: @Sverre If I add `\RaggedRight` and try `\tabfill{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla extracurricular bla bla bla}`, I get “extracurric-ular“ with hyphenation. The same exact code, with `\RaggedRight\leftskip` instead of `\leftskip` (and `\usepackage{ragged2e}`. Please, ask a new question if you can't solve it.

Comment: Yes, me too. Does this mean that ``\RaggedRight`` is defined so that it prefers ``longword [much white space] \\ words`` over ``long- [some white space] \\ word words``? If so, I think this is a poor choice of typography. In my real example, the word that ``\RaggedRight`` won't hyphenate even contains a hyphen, but it still pushes the entire thing to the next line with a _lot_ of whitespace at the end of the previous line.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow. The difference between `\RaggedRight` and `\raggedright` is that the latter doesn't do hyphenation, but sends long words to the next line. The former instead applies hyphenation. And I showed you that it works as intended. I'll stop replying to comments here. If you have problems with the code, please ask a followup question with a proper example showing the issue.

Comment: Question opened at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210504/hyphenation-with-raggedright