# Hyphenation with \RaggedRight

Tags: hyphenation, tabbing, ragged2e

This is based on egreg's [code and comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151638/9077) to [Indenting text in \tabfill (tabbing environment)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151630/indenting-text-in-tabfill-tabbing-environment), in which a command `\tabfill` is defined so that it wraps lines in a `tabbing` environment.

One problem with that approach is that it leads to a lot of white space between words:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \dimen@\linewidth
  \advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin
  \advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab
  \parbox[t]\dimen@{%
    \leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}#1\ifhmode\strut\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\textwidth=.75\textwidth % just to make wrapping more evident

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3.1cm} \= \kill
Column 1 \> Column 2\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{Include longs words like extracurricular}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The proposed solution is to use `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \dimen@\linewidth
  \advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin
  \advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab
  \parbox[t]\dimen@{%
    \RaggedRight\leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}#1\ifhmode\strut\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\textwidth=.75\textwidth % just to make wrapping more evident

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3.1cm} \= \kill
Column 1 \> Column 2\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{Include longs words like extracurricular}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Although this fixes the white space between words, it doesn't hyphenate the word `extracurricular` as I would have expected, instead preferring to leave a lot of white space at the end of the first line:

[image]

So my question is, how can I wrap lines in a tabbing environment, yet maintain "normal" interword spaces and hyphenations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations! You've found a bug in the code. :)

The strut added at the end makes the last word not subject to hyphenation.

Here's a correct version with `\RaggedRight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \dimen@\linewidth
  \advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin
  \advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab
  \parbox[t]\dimen@{%
    \RaggedRight\leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}#1\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\strut\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\textwidth=.75\textwidth % just to make wrapping more evident

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3.1cm} \= \kill
Column 1 \> Column 2\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{Include longs words like extracurricular}\\
bla bla \> \tabfill{bla bla}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also want to set

```
\finalhyphendemerits=0
```

before `\RaggedRight`, so TeX will be less unwilling to hyphenate the last but one line.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \dimen@\linewidth
  \advance\dimen@\@totalleftmargin
  \advance\dimen@-\dimen\@curtab
  \parbox[t]\dimen@{%
    \finalhyphendemerits=\z@
    \RaggedRight\leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}#1\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\strut\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

As suggested in comments by Martin Schröder (the author of `ragged2e`), one can use the special parameter `\RaggedRightLeftskip` and `\dimexpr` (or `calc` features).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabfill[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@totalleftmargin-\dimen\@curtab}{%
    \finalhyphendemerits=\z@
    \RaggedRightLeftskip=2em
    \RaggedRight\hspace*{-2em}#1\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\strut\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: ``\finalhyphendemerits=0`` or ``\finalhyphendemerits=\z@``? (I don't know what they mean, so).

Comment: @Sverre It's the same, since we're in a `\makeatletter` context; `\z@` is some nanosecond faster.

Comment: That looks like a job for `calc` or `\dimexpr`. And there is `\RaggedRightLeftskip`.